# How can I insert HTML attributes with an existing TinyMCE button?

Tags: css, tinymce, editor, visual-editor

When I insert an image into the post editor, select it and click the "align left" button, it automatically adds the *alignleft* CSS class to the image, like so :

```
<img 
    src = "http://www.example.org/media/myimage.png" 
    class = "wp-image-123 size-thumbnail alignleft" 
    height = "141" 
    width = "188" 
/>
```

What I would like to achieve is that it also adds the HTML attibute *align = "left"*, like that :

```
<img 
    src = "http://www.example.org/media/myimage.png" 
    class = "wp-image-123 size-thumbnail alignleft" 
    height = "141" 
    width = "188" 
    align = "left" 
/>
```

**Note** : I am talking specifically about the align buttons that appear over an image when it is selected in the editor :

[image]

Comment: `align` attribute is deprecated in HTML5. You sure want to use it?

Comment: Yes, this is for making email templates and taking care of MS Outlook, which doesn't accept the CSS `float` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following workaround is based on the `wpeditimage/plugin.js` file in the core.

You could enqueue it or test it with:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', function()
{?><script> 
    jQuery(window).load( function( $ ) {
        if( ! $( "#wp-content-wrap").hasClass("tmce-active" ) ) return;
        var editor = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
        editor.on( 'BeforeExecCommand', function( event ) {
            var node, DL, cmd = event.command;
            if ( cmd === 'JustifyLeft' || cmd === 'JustifyRight' || cmd === 'JustifyCenter' || cmd === 'wpAlignNone' ) {
                 node = editor.selection.getNode();
                 DL   = editor.dom.getParent( node, '.wp-caption' );
                 if ( node.nodeName !== 'IMG' && ! DL ) return;
                 node.align = cmd.slice( 7 ).toLowerCase();
             }
        });
    });                                                                 
</script><?php } );
```

Here we use the *Visual* mode checking from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42729/26350). Then you could adjust this to support the case when the *Text* mode is loaded by default.

### Previous answer:

There's no `get_image_tag_align` filter, like the handy `get_image_tag_class` filter. But we can use the `image_send_to_editor` or `get_image_tag` filters to modify the inserted HTML:

**Example:**

```
add_filter( 'get_image_tag', function( $html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size )
{
    if( $align )
    {
        $align = sprintf( ' align="%s" ', esc_attr( $align ) );
        $html  = str_replace( "/>", "{$align}/>", $html );
    }
    return $html;
}, 10, 6 );
```

Comment: Thank you birgire for the great answer, that worked like a charm! With minor tweaks I could adapt it to my needs.

Comment: glad to hear you could adjust it to your needs @mike23